# jQuery Post not posting

Tags: jquery

I'm trying posting the value of a text input field, and for the life of me, it's not posting.

My console is logging the right info. If I fix the variables in the query string, the click inserts the data.

Something is getting lost (I think) when the data is being sent. Any ideas?

HTML

```
 <input class="new_group" type="text" />
 <a class="add_new_group" href="#">add</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('.add_new_group').click(function(){
    //var $add_new_group = $(this);
    var user_id = $(document.body).attr('data-user-id');
    var new_group = $('.new_group').val();

    var data = {
        'user_id' : user_id,
        'new_group' : new_group
    }

    var url = "/wp-content/themes/purplelist/send/new-group.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('group: '+new_group+' user: '+user_id);
            $('.new_group_container').html(new_group);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP to insert into DB

```
include('inc_db.php');

$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
$new_group = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_group']);

$query="INSERT INTO tpl_groups (user_id, group_name) VALUES ($user_id, $new_group)";

mysql_query($query) or DIE(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Set up a failure event and see if it's failing?

Comment: Also, consider using jQuery.post http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Where specifically does it fail?  In the browser's debugging tools, is the POST request being made?  Does it include the key/value pairs you expect?  What is the server's response to that request?  (Note that your client-side code has no error handling callback, so any errors from the server are being ignored.)

Comment: Finally, check to make sure your browser isn't showing a 404 (network tab) on the URL given. It's relative to where your script is

Comment: if you try adding `' '` to variables? `$query="INSERT INTO tpl_groups (user_id, group_name) VALUES ('$user_id', '$new_group')";`

Comment: Sebastian, it worked!

Comment: I will add it as a answer then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `' '` to the variables

```
$query="INSERT INTO tpl_groups (user_id, group_name) VALUES ('$user_id', '$new_group')";
```